# Member not found, igGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am using infragistic igGrid. It's working fine in IE 11 but giving error in IE7

> member not found

in infragistics.lob.js file on below line

```
return $(markup).append(headerText).attr({id:this.id()+"_"+column.key,role:"columnheader","aria-label":column.headerText,tabIndex:this.options.tabIndex}).addClass(headerClass).addClass(customClass).data("columnIndex",index)
```

Please help me resolving this issue.

**EDIT**

I went to `infragistics.lob.js` file to inspect some values as suggested in first comment.

```
console.log(this.id()); // output: id of table to with data is bount
console.log(column.key); // Key column name (RecordId)
console.log(column.headerText); // Key column name (RecordId)
console.log(this.options.tabIndex); // 0
```

Comment: _`this.id()`_ see this or the other object keys you are referring like `column.key, column.headerText, this.options.tabIndex`.

Comment: @Jai, Thanks for the comment, I have added some observations in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem. I just chaged `"aria-label"` (with double comma) to `arialabel` (without comma and hyphen) and it worked. May be someone can explain it better.

Answer (score 2):

- All `Ignite UI` controls and respectively the `igGrid` support IE7 up
  to version 12.2.
- As of [January 12th, 2016,](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) Microsoft does not officially support this browser
  either.

  Versions newer than 12.2 don't guarantee compatibility with IE7.

Comment: But I still needed work around, because my WPF application uses `IE7` and I can't take risk to upgrade it.

Comment: Do you use a WebView?